# Using a php array in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm querying one database to get product stockcodes related to a news article

```
$result = mysql_query('
SELECT stockcode FROM news_related WHERE news = "'.$news_id.'"');
```

then I need to use the data taken from the stockcode column to query a second database. I'm using

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

to put the info in to an array. How do I use that array in the second mysql query?

```
$also_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebProducts
WHERE WebProducts.stockcode THE ARRAY GOES HERE AND WebProducts.visible='Y'") or  die(mysql_error());`**
```

Comment: mysql_* usage is depricated

Comment: Do you mean SELECT * The ALL is depreciated?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tr in a `single query` like,

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM WebProducts WHERE WebProducts.stockcode IN 
             (SELECT stockcode FROM news_related WHERE news = "'.$news_id.'"
               AND WebProducts.visible="Y")');
```

From your **approach** it should be like,

```
$arrStock=array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $arrStock[]=$rows['stockcode'];
}
if(!empty($arrStock))
{
    $also_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebProducts WHERE WebProducts.stockcode
                  IN (".implode(',',$arrStock)." AND WebProducts.visible='Y'");

}
```

You know about the `second parameter` in [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) which is `connection identifier`, in your case there are `two databases` so you should have `2 connections` like `$con1` and `$con2`

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM WebProducts WHERE WebProducts.stockcode IN 
             (SELECT stockcode FROM news_related WHERE news = "'.$news_id.'"
               AND WebProducts.visible="Y")',$con1);// use $con1 for first db
```

and in the **second query**

```
  $also_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebProducts WHERE WebProducts.stockcode
              IN (".implode(',',$arrStock)." AND WebProducts.visible='Y'",$con2);
  // use $con2 for second db
```

**Also** the **mysql_** is `deprecated` and will removed in the `upcoming versions` of **PHP** so use **mysqli_***

Comment: I can't, it's a second database on a different server.

Comment: You should mention that in your question. Your sample code does not make clear that you don't use the same db for everything..

Comment: I did mention it was a second database.

Comment: @user2689525 test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The data is in the $arrStock array but result returns nothing.

Comment: @user2689525 test the above now.

Comment: Yeah I need to switch to using that $con1 $con2 params. Thanks.

I've tried the code you suggested, it should work but for some unknown reason it doesn't!? I'm stumped as to why not.

I've managed to work around my using this as the second query:
"SELECT * FROM WebProducts WHERE (WebProducts.stockcode='$arrStock[1]' 
     OR WebProducts.stockcode='$arrStock[2]' 
     OR WebProducts.stockcode='$arrStock[3]' 
  OR WebProducts.stockcode='$arrStock[4]' ) AND WebProducts.visible='Y'"

Much appreciate your help in this matter

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a simple join for me.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebProducts p
JOIN news_related n
ON p.stockcode = n.stockcode
WHERE n.news = " . $news_id . "
AND p.visible='Y'");
```